# Get particular column from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I need particular columns from datatable to bind it in DataGridView. I have following column.

> Work1     Price       Area     que   Len     bre         size 
>       A              12                x               1             1.2         1            1.2 
>       A                      12                y                2           2              2.2         4.4 
>       A                     12                 z                3          11           1                11

Above is my data table and I need specifyed column i.e **Area, Que, bre, size [Que * (bre * Len)]**
To get this type of data I had used following Linq-to-DataTable query.

```
 var data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select
                (r => new
                {
                    Area = r.Field<string>("Area"),
                    Que = r.Field<int>("Quantity"),
                    Breath = r.Field<decimal>("Breath"),
                    Length = r.Field<decimal>("Length"),
                    totLen = r.Field<int>("Quantity") * (r.Field<decimal>("Breath") * r.Field<decimal>("Length"))
                }).ToList();
```

But its not working, It gives no value, I don't know why??
Can any one tell me how can I do this?
And if there is any other alternate option is available than I love to see that...

Comment: What does give no value, the whole query or the field `totLen`? How have you tried to evaluate the query, where are you using it? Are you sure that there's no exception that is (silently) caught?

Comment: It gives error 
"Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: So it is clear, you need to cast your fields to the correct type. Check the datatype of each columns in your table and cast accordingly in the linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It gives error "Specified cast is not valid."

So you're getting an `InvalidCastException` in the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method.

You have to check which column's type does not match to the one you've specified, for example:

```
totLen = r.Field<int>("Quantity") * r.Field<decimal>("Breath") * r.Field<decimal>("Length")
```

Above will fail if any of the three columns has a different type than the one you've provided. Maybe `Breath` is not a `decimal` but a `double`.

Edit your question and provide the types in database and we could help to identify the correct types.

Comment: Thank you, buddy,I had forgot to set the type of columns, this one is useful and it helped me.
Thanks again...